# How to get attribue in the to_json attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 3 and here is my model

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_reader :price
  belongs_to :product
   def price
    self.product.price * self.quantity
  end

  def as_json(options = {})
    super(:include => [:product])
  end
end
```

Above code works. However now I want my json to also have value for `price` in addition to the other values that I am getting.

How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:methods`:

```
def as_json(options = {})
    super(options.merge(:include => [:product], :methods => [:price]))
end
```

You might want to pay proper attention to any incoming `:include` and `:method` settings in your `options` though. So you might want to use the [block form of `merge`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000759):

```
EXTRAS = { :include => [:product], :methods => [:price] }
def as_json(options = { })
    super(options.merge(EXTRAS) { |k,ov,nv| ov.is_a?(Array) ? ov + nv : nv }
end
```